# How official is the word "subpar"?

Tags: synonyms

How official is the word "subpar"?

Is there a reason not to use it in a document and are there any circumstances under which I should avoid its use? Could the phase "subpar performance" confuse the reader?

Comment: This question does not need an expert to answer it. Google [ define subpar ] and you will find dictionary entries you can consult for any limitations associated with the word.

Answer (score 3):

There is no official academy of the English language. Words are neither official nor unofficial.

That said, '[subpar](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=subpar)' is a standard word that is found in all dictionaries, and has been in [widespread use since the 1960's](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=subpar&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3).